# mongodb: get a 2nd level/ child object with python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongo database collection with 2 query results which looks like this:
[image: collection frommongodb]
each items with an "_id" should be a list and there are some items in a list. now i want to get with python with the pymongo library some querys.i already searchzed the docs but didnt find something useful.

now the question:
what has to be the searchParam here that i can get the list with the _ID = 0 and the TaskID = 0 or 1 or what else?

`db.collection.find_one(searchParam)`

here you have some sample data from the lists :

1.

```json
{
    "_id": 0,
    "name": "todo",
    "items": [{
        "TaskID": 0,
        "name": "task 1",
        "description": "do this an this",
        "date": "2021-06-24",
        "time": "13:30:20.1",
        "subtasks": ["Subtask 1", "Subtask 2", "Subtask 3", "Subtask 4"],
        "done": false
    }, {
        "TaskID": 1,
        "name": "todo 2",
        "description": "something",
        "date": "",
        "time": "",
        "subtasks": [],
        "done": false
    }
}
```

2. 

```json
{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "todo list 2",
    "items": [{
        "TaskID": 0,
        "name": "task 1",
        "description": "do this an this",
        "date": "2021-06-24",
        "time": "13:30:20.1",
        "subtasks": ["Subtask 1", "Subtask 2", "Subtask 3", "Subtask 4"],
        "done": false
    }, {
        "TaskID": 1,
        "name": "todo 2",
        "description": "something",
        "date": "",
        "time": "",
        "subtasks": [],
        "done": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are looking for something like this,

```
db.collection.find({
  '_id' : 0,
  '$or' : [{'items.TaskID' :0}, {'items.TaskID' : 1}]
})
```